# Migrate unknown Oracle database user's encrypted password - 11g hash to 12c database

Tags: oracle, password-recovery

I have tried to search extensively but could not find.Oracle has changed the encryption (spare4) in 12c.

I am trying to see if its possible to migrate / copy the encrypted password hash of a user in 11g database to 12c.

I have done this before on 11g to 11g, but not able to replicate / find how to do this on 11g to 12c.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a database administration question. To "migrate" a hashed password to a different hash algorithm you will need to "unhash" it first, that is, find the original password from its [salted SHA1 hash](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/changes-in-oracle-database-12c-password-hashes/), which is not practical.

You'll need to reset that user's password.

Answer (score 0):

If you *only* have the encrypted hash of the password, then that suggests no-one [else] knows what the password *currently* is and, therefore, no-one should *care* if you simply change it.

Of course, if something *is* using that account and password, then it will break pretty darned quickly, allowing you to uncover these (probably unexpected) dependencies and properly *Document* them.
(You probably want to do this in a Test system first).

If it's a "System" account (like *any* of the Oracle built-in accounts) then you should *change it anyway* because **nobody** outside the DBA team should have access to those credentials anyway!